# Как лучше установить приложение в автозагрузку на Ubuntu Server?

Tags: загрузка, ubuntu

Программа написанная мою, крутится как сервис... нужно запускать при загрузке... куда её лучше воткнуть и как вызвать?

Answer (score 1):

Для демона (службы):

```
sudo update-rc.d имя_демона defaults
```

Для приложения с пользовательским интерфейсом:

```
apt-get install bum
sudo bum
```

- и далее [добавить приложение](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bumdocs.html) в список задач для автозагрузки.