# Ubuntu запуск скрипта python3 при запуске системы

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Как я могу поставить на автозапуск python скрипт при включении системы?
Обычно запускаю скрипт следующей командой в терминале:

```
nohup python /var/www/python/main.py &
```

Ubuntu 18.04
Нужен конкретный пример с PYTHON скриптом и пояснение куда это нужно вставлять

Comment: Изучите systemd, как вариант

Comment: Под юзером или системно?

Comment: я не знаю. главная цель - чтобы при запуске сервера с Ubuntu, запускался этот скрипт

Comment: Значит изучите systemd

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin нехорошо закрывать вопрос про ubuntu дубликатом про centos, это две совершенно разные системы с совершенно разными решениями одних и тех же вопросов. Проголосовал за повторное открытие

Comment: @andreymal, вопросы абсолютно идентичны. даже несмотря на то, что один — про java, а другой — про python. а вот варинтов решения ­— да, как обычно, более одного. и **некоторые** из них, действительно, дистрибутивоспецифичны. вот если бы вопрос касался такого конкретного варианта решения — тогда и стоило трактовать его оригинальным.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в тегах стоит ubuntu. Использовать /etc/init.d в системе с systemd — очень сомнительная затея

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin и да, там в тегах стоит centos. Оба вопроса касаются своих собственных дистрибутивоспецифичных вариантов решений и друг с другом никак не связаны

Comment: @andreymal, systemd ныне и в ubuntu и в centos, потому решение с помощью systemd вы запросто можете опубликовать и под «тем» ответом. и это будет полезно для нашей базы знаний. спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в CentOS 6 не используется systemd. Пока что лишь вы здесь старательно вредите базе знаний :)

Comment: @andreymal, в ubuntu до 16.04 (2016-й год) тоже не использовался. а centos 7 вышел даже раньше, в 2014-м. собственно, redhat — это и есть «рассадник» того самого systemd. и сомнительность тоже сомнительна — возможность исполнения /etc/rc.local в systemd, естественно, присутствует. да, она может быть отключена по умолчанию. потому ваш возможный ответ был бы очень кстати. заранее спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin непонятно, к чему ваш комментарий. В том вопросе чётко указан именно CentOS 6, и никто из нас не имеет права взять и переделать его в CentOS 7, потому что это противоречит намерениям автора. Здесь же указана Ubuntu 18.04, в котором systemd уже есть, и использовать /etc/rc.local это кривой костыль, который поддерживают только для обратной совместимости. Предлагая использовать /etc/rc.local, вы предлагаете использовать костыли и, как следствие, вредите базе знаний, вот)

Comment: @andreymal, отлично, есть более подходящий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/751705/178576), который ждёт хорошего ответа. сообщите, если ответите, я добавлю этот вопрос в списко дубликатов.

Comment: @andreymal, ну или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/143159/178576), если предыдущий предложенный опять не подходит по каким-то критериям. если же опять не подойдёт — скажите, я подберу ещё варианты.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin первый не про то, потому что там интерфейс, а вот второй неплохой вариант

Comment: Может мне кто-нибудь даст какой-то пример?

Comment: На примере моей команды "nohup python /var/www/python/main.py &"